# Updating observations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I apologize for the basic question but I am new to pandas.

I am looking to replace specific observations in a column in a pandas dataframe but am running into issues with memory.

I have this pandas dataframe

| df | RATING |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BB1 |
| 2 | BB2 |
| 3 | BB1 |
| 4 | BB3 |

and I want to change all the RATING variables "BB2" to BB"

I tried this `df.loc[df["RATING"]=="BB2", "RATING"] = "BB"` and receive this error:
`Unable to allocate 1.41 TiB for an array with shape (439547, 439547) and data type float64`

I know this is an elementary question but, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure. That looks like it would work. As an alternative, does `df['RATING'] = df['RATING'].replace({'BB2': 'BB'})` work?

Comment: Your code is ok. The problem is that your dataframe is too big and you are out of memory. Try @Nick's approach

Comment: I get the following error: "<ipython-input-20-35d937197010>:6: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: Your code works on your example DF. Clearly there is more going on than you describe. The error msg refers to 193 Billion elements - which is an incredulous amount of data. What does your real data look like?

Comment: I'm pulling a large amount of financial data. I could take a subset but eventually I will have to use all of it.

Comment: You may well be using the wrong approach to handle such immense amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything "wrong", your machine just doesn't have enough memory to do perform the operation you're attempting.

You can try using [categorical dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) for the column 'RATING'. It stores the data as an array of codes instead or strings, so it saves a significant amount of memory if your string data repeats a lot.

```py
# Convert dtype to category. It will create categories with existing values.
df["RATING"] = df["RATING"].astype("category")

# Rename the category you want to change
df["RATING"] = df["RATING"].cat.rename_categories({"BB2": "BB"})
```

Comment: Wouldn't [rename_categories()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.rename_categories.html) be faster?

Comment: @NickODell Probably would, it totally slipped my mind. Thanks for the suggestion.